# Ruby on Rails - Iterate numbers by decimal for a review rating field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, numbers

I have a Review model which allows for a '1-10' rating system on products. In my form view, here is how I did the field to spit out a dropdown of 1-10...

```
<%= f.select :rating, options_for_select((0..10).to_a, @review.rating) %>
```

Works great, but the team is now wanting to have .5 decimal numbers for the rating system, so something can be rated 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, etc.

However, that has me stumped...how can I alter the above code and iterate through a set of numbers and increment it by .5 each time in Ruby? (Note: Yes, I have already converted my rating column from an integer to a float.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define the increment as so

```
(0..10).step(0.5)
```

Comment: That's it, so simple. Thank you much. Will check this as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Really its so simple, but I am facing an issue as, when I do (1..2).step(0.1) I got the answer as                                                                              [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2.0]. Why I am getting that 1.9000000000000001 ???

Comment: @SwapnilChincholkar - I posted a new answer that should resolve this problem

Answer (score 7):

The answer marked as correct is not accurate. It suffers from floating point accuracy errors - you can read about this common computer science issue here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

To increment this range accurately you should pass a BigDecimal to the step function instead of the default Ruby float:

```
require 'bigdecimal' 
require 'bigdecimal/util'

(0..10).step(0.5.to_d)
```

Comment: You will also need the following code, otherwise to_d won't work

`require 'bigdecimal'`  
`require 'bigdecimal/util'`

Comment: Yes this is the better answer, thanks zarazan. Also use to_d on the range e.g.
```(0.5.to_d..0.8.to_d).step(0.02.to_d).collect {|t| t.to_s}
 => ["0.5", "0.52", "0.54", "0.56", "0.58", "0.6", "0.62", "0.64", "0.66", "0.68", "0.7", "0.72", "0.74", "0.76", "0.78", "0.8"] ```


```(0.5..0.8).step(0.02.to_d).collect {|t| t.to_s}
 => ["0.5", "0.52", "0.54", "0.56", "0.58", "0.6", "0.62", "0.64", "0.66", "0.6799999999999999", "0.7", "0.72", "0.74", "0.76", "0.78", "0.8"]```